# Can not use Angular FormsModule because of an error

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

Every time I am importing FormsModule from '@angular/forms', it gives me the following error:

```
Error: ./node_modules/@angular/forms/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/forms.js 27:12
Module parse failed: Identifier 'ɵngcc0' has already been declared (27:12)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|  */
| import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
> import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
| const NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new InjectionToken('NgValueAccessor');
|
```

Here is my piece of code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

An interesting point in this question is that if I am not including FormsModule in an imports list, code works just fine, but when it is in the list, it causes problems. Simple importing FormsModule seems not to be the problem.

How can I solve it?

Comment: try running `npm ci` and w8 till the result in your application

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file?

Comment: can you please delete node_module folder and run npm install command again?

Comment: `npm ci` solved the problem. Thank you!
I think deleting node_module folder would have the same effect. Anyway, thank you all for trying to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to run `npm ci` and after that `npm install` again. It was enough, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, command `npm ci` have solved my problem (regarding Andrei's solutuion). After performing this command you probably will need to install your packages once again with 'npm install' (just as in my case).

Documentation of `npm ci`:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci